# Save it if this RECORD is not exist?

Tags: django

Models.py

```
#.....
class FilterSave(models.Model):
   def __unicode__(self):
       return "%s" % (self.name)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   customer_type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   tag = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

In my views.py

```
#......
def save_filter(self, filter_name, keyword_filter):
        dict_json = eval(json.dumps(keyword_filter))
        filter_saves = FilterSave.objects.all()
        # Avoid record that already exist
        filter_save = FilterSave(name=filter_name,  customer_type=dict_json["customer_type"], tag=dict_json["tag"])

       # I am trying ....
       for fs in filter_saves:
          if fs.name != filter_name:#just check for a field name
            filter_save.save()
          else:
            print 'already exist '
```

More I tried

# Avoid name collision(just for name field not for a Record)

```
filter_save = FilterSave(name=filter_name, customer_type=dict_json["customer_type"], tag=dict_json["tag"])
exists = FilterSave.objects.filter(name=filter_name)
if not exists:
    filter_save.save()
```

My problems here .I want to save a RECORD if it's not exist in table.Anybody Could help me what I am trying here?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django has a convenience method [`get_or_create(defaults=None, **kwargs)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

> #### [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)
>
> A convenience method for looking up an object with the given **kwargs** (may be empty if your model has defaults for all fields), creating one if necessary.
>
> Returns a tuple of **(object, created)**, where **object** is the retrieved or **created** object and created is a boolean specifying whether a new object was created.

Is that what you mean?